# Creation of Informix Docker Container freezes

Tags: mongodb, docker, informix, database

Hi everyone,
I want to create a docker container with the IBM Informix Developer Database. But everytime, the start script wants to start the Mongo Listener on port 27017, it freezes.
Does anybody has an idea how I can solve this? I followed all instructions of this page:
https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/informix-developer-database/
Thank you for your help!

Comment: How long have you waited for it to "unfreeze". What's the last message?

Comment: I waited for about 2 hours, but nothing happened. The last massage was "starting mongo listener on port 27017".

Comment: Did you reboot it? :p

Comment: Yes. Multiple times. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Ummmmm, why do you think that is hanging there? 
Maybe is just the last message in the start-up.

I did a quick test on a fresh linux box following the instructions on the URL you posted:

After running the command in step 1 ("docker run -it --name iif_developer_edition ......") I get:

```
....
....
(expression)  Chunk 1 is now extendable. 

1 row(s) retrieved.



Database closed.

>>>    Starting up the IBM Informix Database (dev) ... 
*** Startup of dev SUCCESS ***

>>>    Type exit to quit the Startup Shell
>>>       This will stop the container

>>>    For interactive shell run:
>>>      docker exec -it 71280b101fc2 bash

>>>    To start the container run:
>>>      docker start 71280b101fc2 

>>>    To safely shutdown the container run:
>>>      docker stop 71280b101fc2 

IDS-12.10 dev: starting mqtt listener on port 27883
starting rest listener on port 27018
starting mongo listener on port 27017
```

And it waits there, but it is running, everything is properly initialized.

If you attach to the docker container (from a second shell, run "docker ps -a -q" to find the container id, and then "docker attach %container_id%) you can check the engine status.

```
root@irk21:/tmp# docker ps -a -q
71280b101fc2
770421a85b4c
root@irk21:/tmp# docker attach  71280b101fc2

....
....
IDS-12.10 dev: pwd    
/home/informix
IDS-12.10 dev: ls
data  ifx_dev.env
IDS-12.10 dev:    
IDS-12.10 dev: onstat -

IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC8DE -- On-Line -- Up 00:09:46 -- 148084 Kbytes

IDS-12.10 dev: dbaccess sysmaster -

Database selected.

> ^C
IDS-12.10 dev:
```

It should be up an running and all listeners ready to accept connections.

Answer (score 0):

As answered already, you need to attach to the running docker container after you start and exit the shell. In the description page (https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/informix-developer-database/), you can see this step:
4 - To attach to the Informix Docker container (shell)
 `docker exec -it iif_developer_edition bash`